# Scala: is not a member of (String, models.Role)

Tags: scala, slick

I'm working on securing my Scala app. Here's my code:

```
case class User(id: Option[Long],
    role: Role)
```

I'm trying to get the role of a specific user by doing something like this:

```
def authenticate(id: Long): String = db withSession { implicit db: Session =>
    val u = findUserById(id)
    u.role
}

found   : models.Role
[error]  required: String
```

I'm guessing `models.Role` equals `(String, models.Role)`.
I'm expecting to get back either "UserRole" or "AdminRole".  Could someone shed some light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaration of your authenticate method says that it returns String, but you're returning a Role. It seems that the findUserById returnes Role so my guess would be for example:

```
def authenticate(id: Long): String = db withSession { implicit db: Session =>
  findUserById(id) match {
    case ar: AdminRole => "AdminRole"
    case ur: UserRole => "UserRole"
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand that. Could you give me a way to get that role as a string? Wouldn't `toString` return "("Role", Role)?

Comment: @Jon Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. How does the Role class look like?

Comment: I've updated my question. The `roleTypeMapper` maps each one with a string

Comment: @Jon Perhaps I'm not getting what is the goal. What do you want to achieve? If findUserById returns Role, then my answer should do what you need.

Comment: I need it to return a string not a role -> `authenticate(id: Long): String`. (assuming `Role.toString` will return `(Role, "Role")`. Thank you for your patience

Comment: match/case was what I was using but thought there would be a simpler way. I guess this is the preferred way. Thank you for your patience. Btw, do you think this is a good way to set Role based permissions?

Comment: Match is ok, explicit, visible and fails if there is a role for which is no matching case. Sure, role based authorization is one of standard options.